# IE 7 raises error when variable name is same as the element id's name

Tags: jquery

Could anyone kindly clarify this

```
new_pswd = $('#new_pswd').val() // does not work in ie 7 but works in all other
```

When I changed it to

```
newer_pswd = $('#new_pswd').val() // it works even in ie
```

I was thinking may be IE 7 does not support if the variable name is same as the element `id's` name ? or even other versions I don't really know because right now I have IE 7 installed on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a variable equal do an element's id hold that element, as crazy as it sounds, is actually a part of [HTML Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object):

> 6.2.4 Named access on the `Window` object
>
> The `Window` interface supports named properties. The supported property
>   names at any moment consist of the following, in tree order, ignoring
>   later duplicates:
>
> - ...
> - **the value of the `id` content attribute of any HTML element** in the
>     active document with a non-empty `id` content attribute.

Just tested here:

- In IE7 and IE8 you can't assign a value to a variable that is an Element ID.
- In IE 9 and Chrome you can.
- Firefox: There are some side effects, but: version 13 only on quirks mode; version 14 and newer, standard mode.

There's are some useful discussions about this in [DOM Element References as Global Variables](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/07/19/dom-element-references-as-global-variables/) and [DOM: element IDs are global variables](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html).

**Bottom line:** Don't use variable names that are elements' ids. Ultimately, it has unpredictable behaviour. If you plan on using them, please at least read those two articles.